# Programatically disable System Bar (Have Root access)

Tags: android, adb

I am able to disable the System bar using the following adb command using a terminal client:

```
    adb shell service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

However, I want to achieve this programatically. I looked up how to execute adb commands programatically and found below code:

```
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

I replaced "your command" with my adb command above but it does not disable the system bar. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need root access to do this from an app because ADB can access */system/bin/service* but your app cannot (see GID of app and ADB).

```
Process su = null; 
try { 
    su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    String cmd = "service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui\n";
    su.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
    String exit = "exit\n";
    su.getOutputStream().write(exit.getBytes());
    su.waitFor(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally { 
    if (su != null) { 
        su.destroy(); 
    } 
}
```

You should also check out third party libraries for handling su commands: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/451

Comment: It works! But now I am trying to enable it again and I have replaced the cmd string with "am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService"; But it does not work. The same command works through adb.